# Why is "function f(x,x){}" valid syntax in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just found a bug in one of my programs, and it can be reduced to "function f(x,x)" not throwing an error upon declaration...but why is this legal syntax?

Comment: Which one it is: `function f(x,x)` or `function f(x,x){}`? The former is definitely a syntax error, the latter is a function declaration, the body of the function just happens to be empty.

Comment: Any reason why `function f(x,x){}` should not be valid?

Comment: _"I just found a bug in one of my programs"_ What is the bug? Can you reproduce the bug at stacksnippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It is definitely a valid syntax though not meaningful.

Comment: It's valid syntax, despite the argument name being repeated, and behaves like this: `function a(x, x) { return x } a(1, 2) // returns 2`

Comment: _This is a generic question, there's no problem to solve._ **A bit of research could easily provide an answer**. e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Syntax Please, make your homework before post in SO.

Comment: I thought the reason would be obvious...it has two arguments with the same name

Answer (score 0):

It's valid syntax because it's a function declaration:

```
function f(x, x) {

}
```

It just does nothing:

```js
function f(x, x) {}
f();
```

If you want it to actually contain some code, yet still do nothing, you can add a `return` statement:

```js
function f(x, x) { return; }
f();
```